# How to correctly layout scrollable content when using angular material design

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I'm dealing with angular 1 and material design 1, but I'm guessing the principle really isn't specific to those versions. My question is related to the fact that material design sets the height of the body element to 100%. I didn't notice this fact at all the first time I laid out a page, and the content of my page was not inside of an md-content, and was far longer than would fit in the viewport. I noticed strange issues when I tried playing with background images and colors on the body element.

So this led me to believe that material design must assume that the content of the body tag will always fit within the viewport, and that any content that might not fit within the viewport should be contained in a separately scrollable area (i.e. md-content). Is that accurate?

Many tutorial builds I have looked at are set up this way, with a fixed custom header or md-toolbar or md-sidenav directly in the body element, but all other content is inside a scrollable md-content that comprises the main content area of the page.

On the other hand, there are many example pages I've looked at that put the content directly in the body without a containing md-content, and the content grows beyond the borders of the body tag, because the body tag's height is constrained to 100% of the viewport height. This doesn't produce any negative side effects *that I've noticed* except when I started applying background images and colors to the body element. I'm pretty worried, however, that there may be other side effects that I just haven't run into yet (perhaps in more complicated situations where you're opening up dialogs with overlays or something like that?).

1) Can anyone say, definitively, that it is, or is not, "the material design way" to only have scrollable content inside an md-content?

2) And as a follow-up, if it IS, then wow, isn't that kind of a big departure from the way we think of web pages? The document, itself, no longer scrolls, just an area within the document?